# How do I use SQL table alias for more SELECT and with different condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to generate ssrs report for that i need to select 4 values
PreviousNAV , TodaysNAV , @NetChange , @BAMLIndex

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Progreereport]
(
@EndDate DATETIME,
@ComparePeriod VARCHAR(10),
@PortfolioId VARCHAR(50) = '6'
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME =
    CASE
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'Daily' THEN dbo.DateUtility_MakeBusinessDay(DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate), 'LessThanOrEqualTo')
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'Weekly' THEN dbo.DateUtility_GetRelativeDate(@EndDate, 'LessThan', 'End', 'Week', 1)
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'MTD' THEN dbo.DateUtility_GetRelativeDate(@EndDate, 'LessThan', 'End', 'Month', 1)
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'QTD' THEN dbo.DateUtility_GetRelativeDate(@EndDate, 'LessThan', 'End', 'Quarter', 1)
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'YTD' THEN dbo.DateUtility_GetRelativeDate(@EndDate, 'LessThan', 'End', 'Year', 1)
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'LTM' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @EndDate)
        WHEN @ComparePeriod = 'LTD' THEN CAST(Fireball_Configuration.dbo.GetConfigurationValue('Fireball', 'Concerto Credit Opportunity Master Fund I - Inception Date') AS DATETIME)
    END

  DECLARE @PreviousNAV DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @TodaysNAV DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @NetChange DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @BAMLIndex DECIMAL(18,4)

  SELECT ISNULL(@PreviousNAV,0) PreviousNAV 
  FROM Fireball..NAV
  WHERE Date = @StartDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId 

  SELECT ISNULL(@TodaysNAV,0) TodaysNAV 
  FROM Fireball..NAV
  WHERE Date = @EndDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId 

  SELECT @NetChange = (@TodaysNAV - @PreviousNAV ) 

  SELECT @BAMLIndex  = @NetChange / @TodaysNAV

  END
  GO
```

I need above four values to generate report 
but help me to put it into table alias so that i can use it very easily...

Comment: What should `@BAMLIndex` be in case `@TodaysNAV` is `0`?

Comment: Also, how should the values be returned? You are *assigning* `@NetChange` & `@BAMLIndex` with the last two SELECTs, but you are not *returning* the results anywhere in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to return the items in a table?

Do this after your current script:

```
DECLARE @myData TABLE (
   PreviousNAV DECIMAL(18,4),
   TodaysNAV DECIMAL(18,4),
   NetChange DECIMAL(18,4), 
   BAMLIndex DECIMAL(18,4) 
)

INSERT @myData
VALUES (@PreviousNAV, @TodaysNav, @NetChange, @BAMLIndex)

SELECT * FROM @myData
```

---

To return a single column of the four values, add this at the end of your stored procedure:

```
  SELECT @PreviousNAV as [Data] UNION
  DECLARE @TodaysNAV UNION
  DECLARE @NetChange UNION
  DECLARE @BAMLIndex
```

Comment: yes but I want these values in SSRS as a column will I get it??
and what about union after every select column or I have correctly written?

Comment: Yes, you can select each variable with a `UNION`, just remember to give the first an alias so the column has a name.

Comment: hi I have added dataset in ssrs but only previousnav is comoing not todays nav field why???
`My changed SP is` 
`  DECLARE @PreviousNAV DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @TodaysNAV DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @NetChange DECIMAL(18,4)
  DECLARE @BAMLIndex DECIMAL(18,4)
  
  SELECT ISNULL(NAV,0) PreviousNAV 
  FROM Fireball..NAV
  WHERE Date = @StartDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId 
  
  SELECT ISNULL(NAV,0) TodaysNAV 
  FROM Fireball..NAV
  WHERE Date = @EndDate and PortfolioId = @PortfolioId 
    
END
GO`

Comment: @ashuthinks - You aren't using UNION anywhere - I'll update my answer to show how.